# Where does the browsers (Chrome or Firefox) store the images that are loaded for a webpage? How to programmatically access them in Nodejs?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, browser, google-chrome-devtools, puppeteer

I want to know where the images are stored/cached in the browsers when the webpage is loaded. I think they are cached somewhere in the browser storage. Is there a common place where they are stored or does it vary based on webpages?

The end goal is to access them programatically using Javascript. I **don't** want to make http requests on the image urls, instead I want to directly read them from the browser.

Also, I do not want to get into the system storage. Is there a way to read them using [DevTools Protocol APIs](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/) or something like that?

I'm using Puppeteer and couldn't really find any such direct support for images in Puppeteer.

Any leads or help would be appreciated.

Comment: Ultimately that depends on the browser and OS…

Comment: @deceze I am interested in knowing about Chrome, more specifically Chromium. Any leads about that, is it possible through DevTools Protocol APIs?

Comment: Typing `cache` in the protocol site shows me [CacheStorage](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/CacheStorage/).

Comment: I think this is what I need - [getResourceContent](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Page/#method-getResourceContent). But I am unable to confirm if this makes a call to the server or just gets the data from the browser itself.